# Reading a .txt file in Java project

Tags: java, file-io, text-files, java.util.scanner

I am working on a Java program that reads an input 1.txt text file line-by-line, each with a number for example:
2
1 2
2 1
2 1
1 2

The program suppose to take each number and throws to implement Gale-Shapley stable matching.
I need help with getting the program to read the text file.

I am getting the following error message:
Process finished with exit code 0

I have a copy of input 1.txt file in my "src" and main project folder but it still cannot find the file. I tried using VS Code and IntelliJ IDEA and I got the same error message.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Project1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            String inputFile = "input1.txt"; // Specify the correct file path if necessary
            List<List<Integer>> menPrefList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<List<Integer>> womenPrefList = new ArrayList<>();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                menPrefList.add(parsePreferenceList(br.readLine()));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                womenPrefList.add(parsePreferenceList(br.readLine()));
            }

            Map<Integer, Integer> menToWomen = menPropose(menPrefList, womenPrefList);
            Map<Integer, Integer> womenToMen = womenPropose(menPrefList, womenPrefList);

            System.out.println("Output when men propose:");
            printMatching(menToWomen);

            System.out.println("Output when women propose:");
            printMatching(womenToMen);

            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<Integer> parsePreferenceList(String line) {
        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
        List<Integer> preferenceList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String token : tokens) {
            preferenceList.add(Integer.parseInt(token));
        }
        return preferenceList;
    }

    public static Map<Integer, Integer> menPropose(List<List<Integer>> menPrefList, List<List<Integer>> womenPrefList) {
        int n = menPrefList.size();
        Map<Integer, Integer> womenMatches = new HashMap<>();
        boolean[] menEngaged = new boolean[n];

        Queue<Integer> freeMen = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            freeMen.offer(i);
        }

        while (!freeMen.isEmpty()) {
            int man = freeMen.poll();
            List<Integer> preferences = menPrefList.get(man);

            for (int woman : preferences) {
                if (!menEngaged[man]) {
                    if (!womenMatches.containsKey(woman)) {
                        womenMatches.put(woman, man);
                        menEngaged[man] = true;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        int currentMan = womenMatches.get(woman);
                        List<Integer> womanPreferences = womenPrefList.get(woman);
                        if (womanPreferences.indexOf(man) < womanPreferences.indexOf(currentMan)) {
                            womenMatches.put(woman, man);
                            menEngaged[man] = true;
                            freeMen.offer(currentMan);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return womenMatches;
    }

    public static Map<Integer, Integer> womenPropose(List<List<Integer>> menPrefList, List<List<Integer>> womenPrefList) {
        int n = womenPrefList.size();
        Map<Integer, Integer> menMatches = new HashMap<>();
        boolean[] womenEngaged = new boolean[n];

        Queue<Integer> freeWomen = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            freeWomen.offer(i);
        }

        while (!freeWomen.isEmpty()) {
            int woman = freeWomen.poll();
            List<Integer> preferences = womenPrefList.get(woman);

            for (int man : preferences) {
                if (!womenEngaged[woman]) {
                    if (!menMatches.containsKey(man)) {
                        menMatches.put(man, woman);
                        womenEngaged[woman] = true;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        int currentWoman = menMatches.get(man);
                        List<Integer> manPreferences = menPrefList.get(man);
                        if (manPreferences.indexOf(woman) < manPreferences.indexOf(currentWoman)) {
                            menMatches.put(man, woman);
                            womenEngaged[woman] = true;
                            freeWomen.offer(currentWoman);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return menMatches;
    }

    public static void printMatching(Map<Integer, Integer> matching) {
        System.out.print("{");
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : matching.entrySet()) {
            if (!first) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            System.out.print("(" + (entry.getKey() + 1) + "," + (entry.getValue() + 1) + ")");
            first = false;
        }
        System.out.println("}");
    }
}
```

If input1.txt contains:
2
1 2
2 1
2 1
1 2
Then output supposed to be:
Output when men propose:
{(1,1), (2,2)} → It means {(m1, w1), (m2, w2)}
Output when women propose:
{(1,2), (2,1)} → It means ((w1, m2), (w2, m1)}

Comment: This program exits immediately unless exactly one argument is provided. It doesn’t seem to use the argument. My guess is that you aren’t providing one when running it. Maybe you don’t need the `if` statement at the very top?

Comment: Are you supplying the args in your program?

Answer (score 0):

At least, remove the lines:

```
   if (args.length != 1) {
            return;
        }
```

since nowhere in your code you use `args` and this will just end you code with exit code 0 if you do not specify exactly one argument (which we don't know from your question).